# Listed highest CPU usage windows

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line

I can get list the processes but how would I get them to show by highest usage instead of alphabetically?

`Wmic path win32_performatteddata_perfproc_process get Name,PercentProcessorTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) you don't need to make direct calls to [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic), [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.3) is meant to easily query all instances of [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-classes) and [CIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/cimclas) classes and **output objects** which are easy to manipulate. Sorting objects in PowerShell can be done with [`Sort-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2).

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Sort-Object PercentPrivilegedTime -Descending |
    Select-Object Name, PercentProcessorTime
```

You could even go one step further and group the objects by their name with the help of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '#\d+$' } | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Instances = $_.Count
            Name      = $_.Name
            PercentProcessorTime = [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int[]] $_.Group.PercentProcessorTime)
        }
    } | Sort-Object PercentProcessorTime -Descending
```